# Передвижение в Unity netcode for gameobjects

Tags: unity3d

Я пытаюсь изучать Netcode for gameobjects, и хочу использовать архитектуру с удалённым сервером. Я не хочу доверять клиенту поэтому хочу от клиента отсылать "сообщение о желании перемещения" а на сервере уже двигать игрока, собственно у меня все получилось: При подключении клиента я спавнюю префаб игрока (через сервер) и через дикшинари связываю объект игрока с клиентом. Далее на клиенте я считываю ввод с клавиш и отправляю ServerRPC с Vector3 в виде строки, а на сервере беру префаб игрока из дикта с ключем в виде ID игрока и двигаю его.

НО! если я в билде запускаю сервер и в эдиторе перемещаюсь то все ок, но если наоборот то клиент движется сильно медленнее чем если клиент на эдиторе. Собственно в этом и вопрос. в чем я ошибся, или может rpc для такого вообще не подходит и есть способ получше?

повторюсь я не хочу доверять клиенту и позволять ему двигать себя самому.
код ниже, заранее спасибо за советы!

код клиента считывания ввода:

```
public class PlayerNetworkObject : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if (!IsOwner || !IsClient)
            return;

        var direction = Vector3.zero;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            direction += Vector3.forward;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            direction += Vector3.back;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            direction += Vector3.left;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            direction += Vector3.right;

        _serverManager.MoveServerRPC(direction.ToString(), new ServerRpcParams());
    }
}
```

Код ServerManager:

```
 public class ServerManager : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [Inject] private DiContainer container;

    [Header("Prefabs")]
    [SerializeField] private Transform playerMovementNetworkPrefab;

    private Dictionary<ulong, PlayerObjectsData> _playersTable;

    private void Start()
    {
        _playersTable = new Dictionary<ulong, PlayerObjectsData>();

        NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientConnectedCallback += SpawnPlayerMovement;
    }

    #region Spawn
    
    public void SpawnPlayerMovement(ulong clientId)
    {
        if(IsClient)
            return;
        
        if (!_playersTable.ContainsKey(clientId))
        {
            var playerMovement = container.InstantiatePrefabForComponent<PlayerMovementNetwork>(playerMovementNetworkPrefab);
            playerMovement.GetComponent<NetworkObject>().Spawn(true);

            _playersTable.Add(clientId, new PlayerObjectsData()
            {
                playerMovementNetwork = playerMovement,
            });
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Movement

    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    public void MoveServerRPC(string moveDirection, ServerRpcParams serverRpcParams)
    {
        var direction = StringToVector3(moveDirection);

        if (direction.magnitude > 1)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning($"Client {serverRpcParams.Receive.SenderClientId} trying to move too far!");
            return;
        }

        _playersTable[serverRpcParams.Receive.SenderClientId].playerMovementNetwork.Move(direction);

        //MoveClientRPC(moveDirection, new ClientRpcParams() { Send = new ClientRpcSendParams(){TargetClientIds = new []{serverRpcParams.Receive.SenderClientId}}});
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    private void MoveClientRPC(string moveDirection, ClientRpcParams clientRpcParams)
    {
        //_playersTable[clientRpcParams.Receive].Move(StringToVector3(moveDirection));
    }

    private Vector3 StringToVector3(string sVector)
    {
        // Remove the parentheses
        if (sVector.StartsWith("(") && sVector.EndsWith(")"))
        {
            sVector = sVector.Substring(1, sVector.Length - 2);
        }

        // split the items
        string[] sArray = sVector.Split(',');

        // store as a Vector3
        Vector3 result = new Vector3(
            float.Parse(sArray[0].Replace('.',',')),
            float.Parse(sArray[1].Replace('.',',')),
            float.Parse(sArray[2].Replace('.',',')));

        return result;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Код перемещения игрока:

```
public class PlayerMovementNetwork : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [Inject] private ServerManager serverMovementManager;

    [SerializeField] private float speed = 3f;

    public void Move(Vector3 direction)
    {
        transform.position += direction.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"не хочу доверять клиенту и позволять ему двигать себя самому"* - почему нет? Без этого передвижение будет сопровождаться задержкой, не менее пинга до сервера.

Comment: Потому что ни в одной компетитив игре так не делают, из-за того что это можно взломать путем просто изменения переменной через софт, я не говорю что сделаю игру без читов, но в компетитив играх так не делают

Comment: Вы что-то путаете. Наличие диктующего сервера не подразумевает необходимость клиенту ждать получения данных от него, прежде чем обновлять состояние у себя. Клиент должен корректировать свое состояние после получения данных.

Comment: даже в самом пакете от юнити (Netcode for gameobjects) по дефолту клиент не может изменять свое состояние сам, там выходит ошибка и только отнаследовавшись от компонента NetworkTransform и перезаписав один метод ты сможешь это сделать, так же как клиент не может спавнить нчиего, но это обойти уже нельзя. Если делать как вы говорите это получится слишком много передачи данных для одного действия, например для перемещения мне придется
подвинуть клиента
отправить на сервер
получить данные
откорректировать себя
отправить данные на сервер

вместо моего же просто отпаривать и принять данные